# Java Swing Components - why deprecated HTML markup?

Tags: java, xhtml, markup, styling, deprecated

I'm learning Java from a webdev background.  I've been using some HTML inside Swing components, but a little part of me dies every time I see or write

```
<p color=red>Two<br>Lines</p>
```

So I can sleep at night, what's the reason for this poor, deprecated markup?  And, if I use XHTML and inline styling, is my program at risk of being unsupported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing supports only [limited CSS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/CSS.html) without a third-party package; that's just the way it is :)